# Javascript: nested for loops to assign values

Tags: javascript, object, for-loop, nested-loops

I have two arrays:

```
divideArray = [2, 2, 1];
```

which contains 2+2+1 timeslots

and one containing objects:

```
starttimeArray = [{starttime: '06:00:00', divideArrayIndex: 0}, {'09:00:00', divideArrayIndex: 0}, {'12:00:00' divideArrayIndex: 0}, {'15:00:00', divideArrayIndex: 0}, {'18:00:00'divideArrayIndex: 0}];
```

`starttimeArray.length` is equal to the sum of the elements of `divideArray`.

Now I want to go through `starttimeArray` and "assign" every "divideArrayIndex" property to the corresponding index of `divideArray` like:

```
{starttime: '06:00:00', divideArrayIndex: 0}
{starttime: '09:00:00', divideArrayIndex: 0}
{starttime: '12:00:00', divideArrayIndex: 1}
{starttime: '15:00:00', divideArrayIndex: 1}
{starttime: '18:00:00', divideArrayIndex: 2}
```

as `divideArray[0]` has the value 2 for the first two slots, `divideArray[1]` is also 2 for the next 2 slots and `divideArray[2]` (=1) is for the last slot.

I was trying to achieve this using nested for loops, including a while loop, but that is not working and at the moment I absolutely have no clue on how to do it...

```
 for (starttimeArrayCounter = 0; starttimeArrayCounter < starttimeArray.length;) {
   for (divideArrayCounter = 0; divideArrayCounter < divideArray.length; divideArray++) {
       while (divideArrayCounter < starttimeArray[starttimeArrayCounter]) {
    console.log(starttimeArray[starttimeArrayCounter], divideArrayCounter);
    starttimeArrayCounter++;
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post what exactly your expected output is? (not sure what you mean by `'06:00:00' - divideArray[0]`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over `dividerArray`, taking each element as the loop counter while mapping elements from `starttimeArray`:

```js
const divideArray = [2, 2, 1];
const starttimeArray = ['06:00:00', '09:00:00', '12:00:00', '15:00:00', '18:00:00'];

let starttimeIndex = 0;
let divideIndex = 0;
for (let loopCounter of divideArray) {
  while (loopCounter > 0) {
    processResult(starttimeIndex, divideIndex);
    starttimeIndex += 1;
    loopCounter -= 1;
  }
  divideIndex += 1;
}

function processResult(starttimeIndex, divideArrayIndex) {
  console.log({
    starttime: starttimeArray[starttimeIndex],
    divideArrayIndex
  });
}
```

Note: the output is exactly what you've shown in your question, taken as a literal string. It contains the necessary information, feel free to adjust it as needed.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are basically accumulating over the `divideArray` to get index ranges into `starttimeArray`. You can use `reduce` to accumulate the indexes while taking slices of your other array. In each loop take a `slice`, and `forEach` item alter the index property.

This will alter the `starttimeArray` in place:

```js
let divideArray = [2, 2, 1];
let starttimeArray = [{starttime: '06:00:00', divideArrayIndex: 0}, {starttime:'09:00:00', divideArrayIndex: 0}, {starttime:'12:00:00', divideArrayIndex: 0}, {starttime:'15:00:00', divideArrayIndex: 0}, {starttime:'18:00:00', divideArrayIndex: 0}];

divideArray.reduce((start, next, i) => {
    starttimeArray.slice(start, next+start).forEach(item => item.divideArrayIndex = i)
    return start+next
}, 0)
console.log(starttimeArray)
```